# How to retrieve the value from a radio button in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Ok, I've checked a lot of other answers but the solutions posted there are beyond the scope of the class I am taking.  IE we haven't discussed how to do it that way.

Anyways, I'm simply trying to get the value from a radio button here is my html code and my javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function bookTrip()
{
    var arrivalcity;

    arrivalcity = document.reservations.radCity.value;

    alert(arrivalcity);
}
</script>
```

and the actual button looks like this in my html code.

```
    Milwaukee: ($20) <input type="radio" name="radCity" value="20" />
```

When I alert(arrivalcity); all I get is NaN.  I don't understand why, shouldn't it return the string 20??

Allow me to clarify.  I have 3 different city choices.  I have edited it to show exactly what I have when I begin my form.

```
<form name="reservations">
    <p>First Name: <input type="text" name="txtFirstName" />
    Last Name: <input type="text" name="txtLastName" /></p>

    <span style="font-weight:bold;">Arrival City:</span><br />

    Milwaukee: ($20) <input type="radio" name="radCity" value="20" /><br />
    Detriot: ($35) <input type="radio" name="radCity" value="35" /><br />
    St. Louis: ($40) <input type="radio" name="radCity" value="40" />
```

I need to get the value from whatever one is selected.  I can't hardcode it into my script.

Comment: You have invalid HTML now. You can't have more than 1 element with the same ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function will do what you want, through the [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Document.querySelector) method:

```
function selectedRadio(){
    var selValue = document.querySelector('input[name="radCity"]:checked').value;
    alert(selValue);
}
```

[***JSFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/EYQCB/3/)

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Document.querySelector)

Comment: but I don't understand that code at all :(  I can't use something I don't understand how to use.

Comment: There are TONS of reference on basic javascript man. Not sounding mean, but [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll) is the basis of jQuery, which you'll most likely learn before doing any important huge project in JS. :P Nevertheless, I'll add a commented version if I don't manage to make it in a 2 lines code.

Comment: I appreciate the help, but it's just something we didnt' cover in the course this year.  So from a grading standpoint it's useless to use it.  Anyways, I just made a long if statement to get me a value for city.

Comment: Oh I didn't see you tagged the question with `homework`. Take a look at my new function though, it should be useful in the near future. =] I can add a couple comments if you feel like.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a form named reservation in your body?

It will work like this:

```
<form name="reservations">
 <input type="radio" name="radCity" value="20" />
</form>

​function bookTrip()
{
    var arrivalcity;
    arrivalcity = document.reservations.radCity.value;
    alert(arrivalcity);
}
```

See it running here: http://jsfiddle.net/eBhEm/

---

​
**However**, I would prefer this instead:

```
<input type="radio" id="radCity" value="20" />
```

And then use [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById)

```
function bookTrip()
{
    var arrivalcity;
    arrivalcity = document.getElementById("radCity").value;
    alert(arrivalcity);
}
```

See this [running on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QmMqt/).

Comment: I think OP might be interested in obtaining the value of the selected radio. =]

Comment: Yes, my form is named reservations.  I was expecting it to work like what you just edited. However it does not, and I'm not sure why.

Comment: @DanielLoveJr Because, as Fabricio pointed out, your markup is invalid. You cannot have the same id on multiple elements.

Comment: I didn't have that in there initially, I just removed it.

Comment: -1 Accessing a group of radio buttons by name will return a collection of same-named elements. Collections don't have a value property.

Comment: @RobG Which is why I (1) just proposed a solution and (2) Recommended he use the `id`. **Importantly** [this was the version](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/10875433/2) of the question when I gave my answer and he only had one radio button in his code.

Comment: @DanielLoveJr you've changed the html in your post after I answered! You had only one radio button element earlier.

Comment: @gideon—so you should check whether you get a collection or single element (so should I, so I'll up date my question, you get your rep back if you update yours).

Answer (score 0):

You can use querySelector in browsers that support it, but not all browsers in use do. The old fashioned (reliable, robust, works every where) method is to loop over the collection to find the one that is checked:

```
function getValue() {
  var buttonGroup = document.forms['reservations'].elements['radCity'];
  // or 
  // var buttonGroup = document.reservations.radCity;

  // Check for single element or collection, collections don't have
  // a tagName property
  if (typeof buttonGroup.tagName == 'string' && buttonGroup.checked) {
      return buttonGroup.value;

  } else {

    // Otherwise, it's a collection
    for (var i=0, iLen=buttonGroup.length; i<iLen; i++) {
      if (buttonGroup[i].checked) {
        return buttonGroup[i].value;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that the test between an HTMLCollection and DOM element uses a property that DOM elements must have but an HTMLCollection should not have, unless a member of the collection has a name of "tagName".

Answer (score 0):

```
function bookTrip() {
var arrivalcity= document.reservations.radCity;

for (var i = 0, iLen = arrivalcity.length; i < iLen; i++) {
    if (arrivalcity[i].checked) {
        alert(arrivalcity[i].value);

    }
}
```

}

i believe this should help.

see it working here
http://jsfiddle.net/eBhEm/24/